# Pandas dataframe column of floats to percentage style error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a pandas dataframe column of floats to percentage style

```
C
0.9977
0.1234
1.000
..
```

to

```
C
99.77%
12.34%
100%
...
```

To do this, I am doing:

```
df['C'] = df['C'].map(lambda n: '{:.2%}'.format(n))
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Unknown format code '%' for object of type 'str'
```

I also tried `'{:,.2%}'` with the same error...

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First convert column to floats by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['C'] = df['C'].astype(float).map(lambda n: '{:.2%}'.format(n))
```

Also solution should be simplify:

```
df['C'] = df['C'].astype(float).map("{:.2%}".format)
```

EDIT:

Problem is some non numeric values in column.

---

Replace non numeric to `0`:

```
print (df)
                  C
0            0.9977
1            0.1234
2  Covered fraction
df['C'] = pd.to_numeric(df['C'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).map("{:.2%}".format)
print (df)
        C
0  99.77%
1  12.34%
2   0.00%
```

Or remove rows with these values:

```
df['C'] = pd.to_numeric(df['C'], errors='coerce')
df = df.dropna(subset=['C'])
df['C'] = df['C'].astype(float).map("{:.2%}".format)
print (df)
        C
0  99.77%
1  12.34%
```

Comment: This solution doest not work either. I get the following error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: Covered fraction`

Comment: simplified one is just working good

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [df.style](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html):

```
df.style.format({'C': '{:.2%}'})
```

If your series data type is not an issue and want to use it as string try:

```
df['C'] = df.C.apply(lambda x: f"{x[:x.find('.')+3]}%")
df
    C
0   0.99%
1   0.12%
2   1.00%
```

OR if using python <3.6:

```
df['C'] = df.C.apply(lambda x: x[:x.find('.')+3]+'%')
```

Using Jezrael's idea convert to numeric column and invalid strings as 0:

```
df['C'] = pd.to_numeric(df['C'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
df.style.format({'C': '{:.2%}'})
```

Comment: style.format doesn't work either, it happens nothing when its executed :/

Comment: Is your datatype as string?

Comment: @MohitMotwani - Thank you, it is anonymous, so I was curious :)